# How is local connectedness related to connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. Then it can be locally connected. At the other hand, a locally connected topological space can be connected. There is no implication in eather of the cases.

Is there a result (theorem), which makes, under some conditions, the one or the other presumable implication work, and under stronger conditions maybe the equivalence of both ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and locally connected but not connected.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I think you are mixing up path-connectedness with local connectedness.

Comment: Nothing very interesting along these lines, but you can say for instance that for subsets of ${\mathbb R}$, connected implies locally connected.

Comment: Oops. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @MoisheCohen.  But not for subsets of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Of course.